# Controlling over the contour levels and lines in plotly

Tags: python, plotly, contour

I have a custom colorscale for my contour plot.

```
colorscale = [
[0, 'blue'],
[0.28, 'green'],
[0.50, 'yellow'],
[0.65, 'orange'],
[0.75, 'Purple'],
[0.82, 'maroon'],
[0.88, 'magenta'],
[0.93, 'red'],
[0.97, 'brown'],
[1, 'black']]
```

Plotly generates the first several contour line for the blue domain. How to hide them?

I tried to play with different parameters such as

```
zauto=False,
zmin=0.28,
zmax=1, 
contours=dict(start=0.28, end=1, size=0.1, showlines=True).
```

**Size** sets the step between each contour level. So I wrote:

```
contours=dict(size=[0.28, 0.22, 0.15, 0.1, 0.07, 0.06, 0.05, 0.04, 0.03], showlines=True)
```

or

```
contours=dict(size=[0.28, 0.50, 0.65, 0.75, 0.82, 0.88, 0.93, 0.97, 1], showlines=True)
```

hoping that the step between the first two contour levels would be 0.28, between level#2 and level#3 - 0.22, and so on, but it doesn’t work.

```
line=dict(color='blue', width=0.2) is also not a good solution.
```

I want something like this:

```
for The_First_N_Contour_Levels:
    contours = dict(showlines=False)
```

I used the [plotly reference documentation](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#contour-contours-size)